# Using TensorFlow to extract meta data containing numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am new to ML/DL but I am looking for a way to extract meta data from text and I figured ML could be a good solution.

**Objective**

Input: Sentence containing a field descriptor and a value/values e.g:

> "Non-current assets  5 675 5 512 4 789 4 586"
>
> "Cash and cash equivalents 909 861   912   630"
>
> "Inventories, trade and other receivables and other current assets   3 756 2 998 2 864 2 834"
>
> "Total assets  10 340 9 372 8 565 8 051"
>
> "Equity   5 649 4 560  2 365 1 969"
>
> "Non-current liabilities  2 438 2 403 3 270 2 407"
>
> "Current liabilities  2 253 2 409 2 931  3 675"

I have done some research and know that the words need to be embedded (Using Word2Vec or something similar). But how are the numbers handled?

Output: Tuple {field: value}

> {non_current_assets: 5675}
>
> {cash_and_cash_equivalents: 909}
>
> {total_assets: 10340}
>
> {equity: 5649}
>
> {non_current_liabilities: 2438}
>
> {current_liabilities: 3756}
>
> {inventories: 3756}

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to solve using ML? If so:

   1. How should I format the input data?
   2. What algorithm is best suited for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're question is not completely clear.

If you just have strings with text then numbers and you want {text: number} you should just split on int character and not doing ML, I your string are within in more complete text document, but it would be easier to have a full example then.

if your sentence is within a text like foe example:

```
text = " If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can use pip. Non-current assets 5 675 5 512 4 789 4 586. We also expect cash equivalents 909 861 912 630 in toal"
```

You could use part of speech tagging and chunking to detect nominal groups that are before numbers:

like in this: https://medium.com/@acrosson/extracting-names-emails-and-phone-numbers-5d576354baa

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
stop = stopwords.words('english')
document = ' '.join([i for i in text.split() if i not in stop])
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(document)
sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
```

then sentences is:

```
[[('If', 'IN'),
  ('import', 'NN'),
  ('failing', 'VBG'),
  ('due', 'JJ'),
  ('missing', 'VBG'),
  ('package', 'NN'),
  (',', ','),
  ('use', 'NN'),
  ('pip', 'NN'),
  ('.', '.')],
[('Non-current', 'JJ'),
  ('assets', 'NNS'),
  ('5', 'CD'),
  ('675', 'CD'),
  ('5', 'CD'),
  ('512', 'CD'),
  ('4', 'CD'),
  ('789', 'CD'),
  ('4', 'CD'),
  ('586', 'CD'),
  ('.', '.')],
[('We', 'PRP'),
  ('also', 'RB'),
  ('expect', 'VBP'),
  ('cash', 'NN'),
  ('equivalents', 'NNS'),
  ('909', 'CD'),
  ('861', 'CD'),
  ('912', 'CD'),
  ('630', 'CD'),
  ('toal', 'NN')]]
```

And you can define regex based on grammar to detect nominal group followed by number like:

```
grammar = """MATCH:{<JJ><NNS><CD>}""" #grammar would need to be completed
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
for sentence in sentences:
  print(cp.parse(sentence))
```

which return:

```
(S
  If/IN
  import/NN
  failing/VBG
  due/JJ
  missing/VBG
  package/NN
  ,/,
  use/NN
  pip/NN
  ./.)
(S
  (MATCH Non-current/JJ assets/NNS 5/CD)
  675/CD
  5/CD
  512/CD
  4/CD
  789/CD
  4/CD
  586/CD
  ./.)
(S
  We/PRP
  also/RB
  expect/VBP
  cash/NN
  equivalents/NNS
  909/CD
  861/CD
  912/CD
  630/CD
  toal/NN)
```

It would be much more difficult to do it from scratch with tensorflow if you're not an expert I think

Comment: Thanks for the input, I agree that using part of speech tagging sounds much better for extracting the numbers. The problem is that the label e.g. "Non-current" has other abbreviation. But I guess I could use TensorFlow to classify the different variations?